# Give access to a view in the databricks table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have below permission level assigned to user in the Databricks.. He is able to see the schema in a View of a table but not the data in the view. What wrong am I doing or what permission i am missing?

> Databricks Shared cluster-- User A permission --- Can Restart

> Databricks Catalog- User A permission -- Use Catalog, Use Schema

> Databricks Schema in the Catalog-- User A permission - use Schema

> Databricks Table - User A permission- No permission

> Datbricks View in the table - User A permission - SELECT

Result is User A is unable to read the data from the View but he can see the schema once he start the cluster. I don't want him to give permission to the table as it has lot more data then user should have access to and that was the reason a view was created.